# Presto DDL on S3 using FileHiveMetastore not working

Tags: amazon-s3, presto

I tried to connect Presto to S3 using FileHiveMetaStore with below configurations , but it when I am trying to create table with the statement mentioned but it fails with error message  mentioned below . could any one let me know if the configurations mentioned are wrong.

I could see that it is possible as some one has already mentioned  it is possible to connect

reference thread :- [Setup Standalone Hive Metastore Service For Presto and AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932907/setup-standalone-hive-metastore-service-for-presto-and-aws-s3)

error message:- com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: 33F01AA7477B12FC)

```
**connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore=file
hive.metastore.catalog.dir=s3://ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prestos3test/
hive.s3.aws-access-key=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
hive.s3.aws-secret-key=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
hive.s3.endpoint=http://prestos3test.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
hive.s3.ssl.enabled=false
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083**
```

### External Table Creation

**CREATE TABLE PropData (
  prop0 integer,
  prop1 integer,
  prop2 varchar,
  prop3 varchar ,
  prop4 varchar

)
WITH (
  format = 'ORC',
  external_location = 's3://prestos3test'
)**

Thanks
Santosh

Comment: This question was also raised here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/LNLCpdqkvQU

Comment: Hi Grzegorz , 

I am trying to find help in multiple forums as I am not able to proceed further with my learning.

Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help form other corners ,thought it would be helpful to others hence documenting necessary config in below .

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore=file
hive.metastore.catalog.dir=s3://prestos3test/
hive.s3.aws-access-key=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
hive.s3.aws-secret-key=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
hive.s3.ssl.enabled=false
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083
```

Thanks
Santosh

Comment: would you mind explaining a bit more.. like what changed and why was this happening?  I am having similar error with TRINO but don't understand why you're not using S3 endpoint etc... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839592/first-time-trying-to-add-table-to-hive-metastore-aws-notfound-error

Comment: for giggles i tried the `hive.metastore` entries you had.. but they seem to be if you're running metastore locally .. which i am not .. all other things on there I have already set.. so makes me wonder if it's the s3 endpoint now..